# QDeclarativeItem mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) not working

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt4.8

I'm trying to catch mouse events in a transparent QDeclarativeItem, wrap it around all the other elements in QML and log information about mouse events in the whole program.
**mouseMoveEvents(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *)** however is executed only when **mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *)** is implemented and mouse button is pressed.

In a QWidget I would sovle this by calling **setMouseTracking(true)**.

How to do this in a QDeclarativeItem?

Comment: Both: capturing on transparent objects, or having event transparency on opaque objects is tricky on current QT versions.

Comment: I'm using qt4.8 and QtQuick 1.1. Filling the Item with a color does not change anything.

Comment: Did you set setMouseTracking(true); ?

Comment: No. setMouseTracking(bool) is not a member of qDeclarativeItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by using **hoverMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *)** and setting **setAcceptHoverEvents(true)**. It works the same way as mouseMoveEvent, but is being called when mouse button is not pressed too.